# Where are save games stored?

Tags: the-dark-eye-blackguards

I'm trying to find the save games for Blackguards on OS X, but I can't seem to track them down.

Does anyone know where they are saved?

Comment: Did you look to see if they're in the package contents for the game itself?  Otherwise, I would look to see if they're in the application support folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the save games for this here

`/Users/david/Library/Application Support/de.daedalic.blackguards1`

In this folder is a profile dir which is all numbers, and then a `save` folder which contains your save games.

Thought I would add the Windows location, for completeness.

`C:\Users\Neon\AppData\Local\Daedalic Entertainment GmbH\Blackguards\`

Comment: In general, with any game on OSX that is a good place to check first.